# SwiftUI tvOS: NavigationLink with button style custom disables auto scroll in List view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tvos, uifocusguide

I want to achieve a `.buttonStyle(.card)` scrolling behaviour in custom button style in `NavigationLink`.

[image]

```
NavigationLink {
    Color.blue
} label: {
    listItem(model: model)
}
.buttonStyle( 
   HomeCardStyle(onFocusChange: { isFocused in 
      if isFocused { 
         // My Custom Code 
      } 
   }) 
)
```

**Button Style Code:**

```
struct HomeCardStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let onFocusChange: (Bool) -> Void
    @Environment(\.isFocused) private var focused: Bool

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .overlay(
                Rectangle()
                    .stroke(
                        Color.yellow,
                        lineWidth: focused ? Constants.UI.Padding.xxSmall : Constants.UI.Padding.zero
                    )
                    .shadow(
                        color: focused ? .yellow : .clear,
                        radius: Constants.UI.Padding.xxxxxSmall,
                        x: Constants.UI.Padding.zero,
                        y: Constants.UI.Padding.one
                    )
            )
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .padding(.horizontal, focused ? Constants.UI.Padding.default : Constants.UI.Padding.zero)
            .scaleEffect(focused ? Constants.UI.Frame.homeFeaturedItemScaleMedium : Constants.UI.Frame.homeFeaturedItemScaleRegular)
            .animation(.linear(duration: Constants.UI.AnimationDuration.indicator), value: focused)
            .onChange(of: focused) { newValue in
                onFocusChange(newValue)
            }
    }
}
```

I have a requirement to show a custom indicator that's why using a custom button style.
So I have a horizontal list of the above as shown in the image below:

Now the problem is in the case of `.buttonStyle(.card)`, the list automatically scrolls to the top when the focus comes to the `NavigationLinks`.
But that is not working if I'm using a custom button style.

How I can achieve same behaviour?

Comment: SwiftUI on tvOS is very buggy and incomplete in my experience. You probably need to either make `.card` work or rebuild that list in UIKit.